# System wide Validation Callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to setup a system wide validation callback?

I want to write a logger for every validation failure that occur in any model. This callback should not change the behaviour of any other callback that is setted in the models.

I need it to provide faster support to my customers, my idea is to log all validation errors so the support team is able to find out what is going on faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although @MurifoX's answer might work with some configuration I prefer to avoid inheritance from ActiveRecord::Base when possible. Since SuperModel inherits from ActiveRecord::Base it may look like its an actual model which has a representation in the Database side, whereas it only exists to be inherited from.

In my opinion, a better solution to your problem would be [Ruby Mixins](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html):

```ruby
# lib/validation_logger.rb
module ValidationLogger
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      after_validation :log_validation
    end
  end

  def log_validation
    #custom log here
  end
end
```

Now you should just `include ValidationLogger` in models you would like to log.

Comment: Yeah, your answer is a bit more elegant. Although both work in practice. =]

Comment: Thanks :) As I said your answer will work perfectly but I do prefer to avoid inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base when possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe make all your models inherit from one common super-model that inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`.

```
def FirstModel < SuperModel
end

def SecondModel < SuperModel
end

def ThirdModel < SuperModel
end
```

And then, you put your callback on the super-model:

```
def SuperModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_validation :do_your_thing

  def do_your_thing
    # stuff
  end
end
```